# Get an access token from box API from asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, access-token, restsharp, box

I have my auth code, client id, client secret and now to upload a file to my box account, I need to have the ACCESS TOKEN. I am using below code copied somewhere in stackoverflow to get ACCESS TOKEN.

```
public string GetAccessToken(string code, string ClientId, string ClientSecret)
    {
        RestClient rs = new RestClient();
        string grant_type = "authorization_code";
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        IRestRequest reuest = request;
        string strHeaders = null;
        RestResponse response = default(RestResponse);
        IRestResponse resp = response;
        string strResponse = null;

        try
        {
            rs.BaseUrl = "https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token";
            request.Resource = "oauth2/token";
            strHeaders = string.Format("grant_type={0}&code={1}&client_id={2}&client_secret={3}", grant_type, code, ClientId, ClientSecret);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", strHeaders);
            resp = rs.Execute(reuest);
            strResponse = resp.Content;

            return strResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

The content type of the response is HTML and not JSON as they mentioned in their docs page. May you please help me how to get an access token from BOX API using asp.net application?

Comment: What html response do you get. Take a look, because It might be an error message. Do you get a successful reponse code?

Comment: Yes. Receiving successful response code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below piece of code did the work:

```
        public string GetAccessToken()
        {
        string param = string.Format("grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}", CODE, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);

        var client = new RestClient("https://api.box.com/oauth2/token/");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", param, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        var json = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

        return Convert.ToString(json["access_token"]);
        }
```

Kindly note the Header and Parameter I have added in the code.